# can't make a prediction model of energy consumption

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, statsmodels

I am trying to make a model for predicting energy production, by using VARMA(or VAR) model. 
(**If you have any recommendations other than VARMA or VAR, please let me know.**)

The data I can use for training is as following;

（https://github.com/soma11soma11/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge/blob/master/challenge1/data/training_dataset_500.csv）

```
ID  Label   House   Year    Month   Temperature Daylight    EnergyProduction
0     0       1     2011     7         26.2      178.9         740
1     1       1     2011     8         25.8      169.7         731
2     2       1     2011     9         22.8      170.2         694
3     3       1     2011     10        16.4      169.1         688
4     4       1     2011     11        11.4      169.1         650
5     5       1     2011     12         4.2      199.5         763
...............

11995 19     500    2013     2          4.2      201.8         638
11996 20     500    2013     3         11.2        234         778
11997 21     500    2013     4         13.6      237.1         758
11998 22     500    2013     5         19.2      258.4         838
11999 23     500    2013     6         22.7      122.9         586
```

As shown above, I can use data from July 2011 to May 2013 for training.
Using the training, I want to predict energy production on June 2013 for each 500 house.

By using `statsmodels.api.tsa.filters.hpfilter`, I succeeded to get rid of trend component from "Daylight".

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm


df = pd.read_csv('../../data/training_dataset_500.csv')

x = df.loc[df.House==1, 'Daylight']
x_smoothed, x_trend = sm.tsa.filters.hpfilter(x, lamb=129600)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4), ncols=3)
axes[0].plot(x)
axes[0].set_title('raw x')
axes[1].plot(x_trend)
axes[1].set_title('trend')
axes[2].plot(x_smoothed)
axes[2].set_title('smoothed x')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have 2 questions(stack) here.

**Stack1**

I can not remove seasonal component.

Although I can get rid of the trend component, I cannot remove seasonal component to make the time series data stationary.
(I need to make the time series data stationary in order to get a good prediction.)

**Stack2**

I want to implement VARMA(or VAR) model to get the prediction.
But writing the models are difficult for me and cannot write a proper code...

Again, **If you have any recommendations other than VARMA or VAR, please let me know.**

Following are my code.(I tryed to implement VAR model)

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as st
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar as var
import statsmodels.api as sm

data_train = pd.read_csv('../../data/training_dataset_500.csv')
data_test = pd.read_csv('../../data/test_dataset_500.csv')
data_set = pd.read_csv('../../data/dataset_500.csv')

rng=pd.date_range('7/1/2011', '6/1/2013', freq='M')


def mape_of_var(house, predfile, mapefile):
    sum0 = 0
    f_pred = open(predfile, 'w')
    f_mape = open(mapefile, 'w')
    pred_writer = csv.writer(f_pred)
    pred_writer.writerow(['House','EnergyProduction'])
    for i in house:
        data = data_train[data_train.House==i][['EnergyProduction','Daylight','Temperature']].set_index(rng)
        data_diff = data.diff().dropna()
        model = var.var_model.VAR(data_diff)
        results = model.fit(4, trend='nc')
        lag_order = results.k_ar
        data_pred = results.forecast(data_diff.values[-lag_order:],1)[0,0]+data.EnergyProduction[-1]
        sum0 = sum0 + abs(data_pred-data_test.EnergyProduction[i-1])/data_test.EnergyProduction[i-1]
        pred_writer.writerow([i,data_pred])

    mape = round(sum0/len(house),3)
    f_mape.write(str(mape))
    f_pred.close()
    f_mape.close()

#return mape


print 'MAPE(500 houses): ' + str(mape_of_var(range(1,501), 'pred_all.csv','mape_all.txt'))
```

and when I implemented this code, I got a following error;

```
  (DataVizProj)Soma-Suzuki:Soma Suzuki$ python examine.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examine.py", line 41, in <module>
    print 'MAPE(500 houses): ' + str(mape_of_var(range(1,501), 'pred_all.csv','mape_all.txt'))
  File "examine.py", line 24, in mape_of_var
    data = data_smoothed[data_smoothed.House==i][['EnergyProduction','Daylight','Temperature']].set_index(rng)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2625, in set_index
    frame.index = index
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2161, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas/src/properties.pyx", line 65, in pandas.lib.AxisProperty.__set__ (pandas/lib.c:42548)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 413, in _set_axis
    self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2219, in set_axis
    'new values have %d elements' % (old_len, new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 23 elements
```

Any infomation would be helphul.

Comment: A lot of what you're trying to accomplish can be approached with ordinary math equations.

Comment: Hi! Robert!! Thanks for your comment!
I see... But how..?

Comment: Your traceback fails on pandas reindexing in `data = data_smoothed...`, but there is no such line in your function. There is a similar line with data_train, but that part looks independent of the var code, and you need to check your data frame and reindexing.